# Only if isset() and value equality

Tags: php

Just a simple php question, i have this:

```
if(isset($_GET['i'])) { if($_GET['i']=='dash') {
```

It is possible to use one **IF**? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [logical operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

```
if (isset($_GET['i']) && $_GET['i'] == 'dash') {
```

This will test that both conditions `return true` in the test.

Comment: Just to clarify, `&&` means `and`, you could use `||` for `or` if you wanted either condition to match.

Comment: What you might be asking is whether the `if($_GET['i']=='dash')` will throw an error if `$_GET['i']` is not set; it won't. PHP uses what's called "lazy evaluation," so if `$_GET['i']` is not set, PHP knows the entire if statement will fail so it will not evaluate `$_GET['i'] == 'dash'`.

Comment: By the way if the first condition returns `false`, the second one will never be tested! So you simply can access `$_GET['i']` after you tested the existence in the IF.

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way:

```
function initGet($var, $default=''){
    if(!isset($_GET[$var])) return $default;
    return $_GET[$var];
}
```

So you can check it easy:

```
if(initGet('i')=='dash'){
```

And you could add a default value if needed:

```
if(initGet('i', 'dash')=='dash'){
     // would be true if $_GET['i'] is not set
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use [`array_intersect_assoc`](http://php.net/array_intersect_assoc) to check both conditions at once:

```
if (array_intersect_assoc($_GET, array("i" => "dash"))) {
```